# Contar registros em Doctrine

Tags: mysql, doctrine

Preciso retornar o número total de registros de um campo de uma tabela, e também contar a quantidade de registros de um determinado id.

Preciso contar os dados de uma tabela de votos de uma enquete por isso preciso contar os valores de um campo para fazer o calculo de porcentagem.

Na tabela votos eu tenho o campo `id` e o campo  `opcao` onde mostra as opção exemplo: bom , ruim , ótimo .

Preciso contar quantos votos tenho no total de todas as opções e também contar quantos votos eu tenho em cada `opcao`.

Como fasso isso em Doctrine ?

Comment: Tem algum exemplo de código que está tentando fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Use o `EntityManager` para fazer a seguinte DQL:

```
SELECT v.opcao, count(v.id)
FROM Voto v
GROUP BY v.opcao
```

Você receberá como resultado um *array* de *arrays*. Dê um `print_r` esse resultado para ver os valores retornados.

Não se esqueça de alterar o nome da tabela e dos campos para o seu caso.

Comment: Vou tentar, desde já agradeço.